# some recommendation to improve the time complexity

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity

I'm trying to find the number of palindromes in a certain range using the Python code below:

```py
def test(n,m):
    return len([i for i in range(n,m+1) if str(i) == str(i)[::-1]])
```

Can anyone discover any other ways to make this code simpler in order to reduce its time complexity, as well as any potential missing conditions that my function may not have addressed?

Some recommendations to enhance the temporal complexity and mark on conditions that I haven't handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can eliminate for loop and you can use recursion for eliminating time complexity

below is the code which has O(log10n) time complexity

```html
def getFirstDigit(x) :
    while (x >= 10) :
        x //= 10
    return x


def getCountWithSameStartAndEndFrom1(x) :
    if (x < 10):
        return x
    tens = x // 10
    res = tens + 9
    firstDigit = getFirstDigit(x)
    lastDigit = x % 10


    if (lastDigit < firstDigit) :
        res = res - 1

    return res


def getCountWithSameStartAndEnd(start, end) :
    return (getCountWithSameStartAndEndFrom1(end) -
        getCountWithSameStartAndEndFrom1(start - 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

So here's an idea to build off of: For an n-digit number, there will be `O(2^n)` numbers less than `n`. For now, forget the lower bound. Checking each in turn will therefor take at least that long.

However, every palindrome is the repeat of a number of half that length - there can only be `2^(n/2)` palindromes of length `n`. This is a much smaller number. Consider searching that way instead?

So for a number of the form `abcd`, there are two palindromes based off of it - `abcddcba` and `abcdcba`. You can therefor find all panidromes up to length 8 by instead starting from all numbers up to length 4 and finding their generated palindromes.